# How to write a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

I would like to write a vector p1 in R which will contain all the values between 0.5 and 1.

I try to write p1=c(0.5:1) but that does not work, but if we write c(1:5) that works.

Any ideas how to write it?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: There are infinitely many numbers between 0.5 and 1.  How many decimal points?

Comment: a vector containing the values from 0.5 to 1 with two decimal points

Comment: Then it would be `seq(0.5, 1, by = 0.01)`

Comment: Downvote for a total lack of research. This is covered in the official 'An Introduction to R' - http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Generating-regular-sequences and probably thousands of other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the decimal points in `seq`

```
> seq(0.5, 1, by = 0.01)
 [1] 0.50 0.51 0.52 0.53 0.54 0.55 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59 0.60 0.61 0.62
[14] 0.63 0.64 0.65 0.66 0.67 0.68 0.69 0.70 0.71 0.72 0.73 0.74 0.75
[27] 0.76 0.77 0.78 0.79 0.80 0.81 0.82 0.83 0.84 0.85 0.86 0.87 0.88
[40] 0.89 0.90 0.91 0.92 0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1.00
```